# How to check modified value in a model's before_save callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

**How can I read the value that a controller has set in a before_save callback?**

Example:

I have a model with a `url` field. Before saving, I want to check if the url was changed. If so, do some stuff with both the new and old url.

**Is that possible?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
before_save { |m| if m.url_changed? ... }
```

Also see the docs on [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)

Comment: Thanks for changing your mind and undeleting your answer, this is the right approach. In particular, the `url_changed?`, `url_was`, and `url_change` methods are of interest.

Comment: I ended up using paper_trail to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

better way

```
before :todo, if: :first_name_or_last_name_changed?
```

and your `todo` method

> *def first_name_or_last_name_changed?* 
>    *first_name_changed? || last_name_changed?*
> *end*

Comment: Can you [edit] to reformat as a code block (Ctrl-K or four leading spaces) so this is more readable? Be sure to check the preview below the edit box.

Comment: I think this is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If it has changed it should be in the `params` hash. If it hasn't changed it shouldn't be in there.   Therefore, you can put this custom handling into the controller, or in a method on the model that does this.

If you really want to access it in`before_save` check the documentation on ActiveRecord callbacks, and you will see how to access the before and after values.

Comment: No, this sort of thing does not belong in the controller, the model should be responsible for managing its own internals. And what happens if `url` is modified as a side effect of setting a different property? Perhaps a `before_validation` hook looks at some other property and updates `url`, that's none of the controller's business. Or perhaps `before_save` is being used to track the model's revision history, that's none of the controller's business either.

Comment: Understood. I was just offering multiple approaches, including the one that utilizes `before_save`. The original asker didn't really go into what it was that they wanted to do based on the value of the url (e.g. redirect somewhere else - something done in the controller), so I didn't want to assume what the purpose was. I was just pointing out the various places you could get to this information.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this thing but it did not work out

```
#Non-working code
before_save: record_old_value
after_save: record_change

def record_old_value
   @old_value = self.field
end

def record_change
   if @old_value==self.field
      create_record_in_history :old_value => @old_value, :new_value => self.field
   end
end
```

The reason it didn't work out was because we set self.field=new_value so in before_save it is not accessible. But rails has some more Active-record function like **field_changed** which can directly be used in both before_save and after_save. So I ended up with this solution

```
#working code
after_save :run_function
def run_function
   @old_value = field_was
   if @old_value==self.field
      create_record_in_history :old_value => @old_value, :new_value => self.field
   end
end
```